# How to export data from a Cordova JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have an iOS app made with JavaScript and Cordova. It uses Local Storage to store data on the device between sessions. I'd like to give users a way to export their data, probably in CSV format.

One thing that would most certainly work would be to use `mailto:` and put the data in the body of the email. But it would be way more elegant to create an actual `.CSV` file and give them some way to export it, perhaps as an email attachment or through the native share sheet.

What's the most appropriate, relatively easy, way to do this?

Comment: You might consider writing it to a file using the File plugin.

Comment: I looked into that, but it looked like the only way to get those files out is through iTunes when the phone is synced to a computer? Am I wrong? How does the File plugin export data? (I've looked at the documentation but it's vague on this point.)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file Take a look at the `Where to store files` section.  you probably want to use `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`

Comment: OK that is awesome because `cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory` will sync my data to iCloud, so I should use that instead of Local Storage for the regular data store. But for export ... how does the user get the data? (It looks like `cordova.file.externalDirectory` is not supported on iOS?)

Comment: @Alesh Houdek , as you said externalRootDirectory is not supported in iOS. You can write the file to application data directory and open the same using cordova file opener plugin which will prompt the user to open the file in respective app which can then be saved manually.

Comment: @Gandhi That sounds promising I'll try it. Thanks!